# Increasing the width of line drawn using Shape Renderer in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am drawing a line using Shape Renderer in LibGDX and i am using Orthographic Camera in my code, so to increase the width i used

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
int lineWidth = 8; // pixels
Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(lineWidth / camera.zoom);
```

Now, I get a wider line. But the problem arises when the screen power goes off and then turns on, the line becomes the normal one again. How to keep the width constant?

Comment: write the same code except for initializing camera in resume func of screen... this will work for u

Comment: When i initialize my camera in the resume function, my camera position sets to (0,0,0) in my screen.

Comment: write only last two lines in resume func

Comment: Writing it in the resize function helped me! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*ShapeRenderer* has the method *rectLine* that is intended to be used to draw thick lines. It draws a rotated filled rectangle with the smaller opposite sides centered on the points passed to it (as coordinates or as *Vector2* objects). The method has the parameter *width* to set the line width.

You can see the documentation [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#rectLine-float-float-float-float-float-)

Example:

```
shapeRenderer.rectLine(new Vector2(x1,y1),new Vector2(x2,y2),lineWidth);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see here:
[libgdx Shaperenderer line .. How to draw line with a specific width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023913/libgdx-shaperenderer-line-how-to-draw-line-with-a-specific-width)
And here:
[Libgdx gl10.glLineWidth()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680908/libgdx-gl10-gllinewidth)
And here:
[Why Libgdx Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(width); does not react to change projection properities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349284/why-libgdx-gdx-gl10-gllinewidthwidth-does-not-react-to-change-projection-prop)

Playing with the line width in the shaperenderer isn't the best way to do what you want to achieve.

Try using a 1x1 white TextureRegion (you can change the color the Batch draws it with later), and draw it with the width and height that you desire:

```
batch.draw(region, x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: You can't possibly draw a line (other than straight vertical or horizontal) with just x,y,width and height.....think about it. You'd have to rotate it at least...