# How to set thickness of an arc using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I have been playing around with `LibGDX`.

I cannot figure out how to draw an arc with a certain thickness on a `2D canvas`. This is what I got so far:

```
    //draw the outline of the rectangle
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(255/255.0f, 109/255.0f, 120/255.0f, 1f);
    shapeRenderer.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, 270);
    shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: found this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023913/libgdx-shaperenderer-line-how-to-draw-line-with-a-specific-width

Comment: I dont understand how to link this to my arc :(

Answer (score 2):

Not sure here been a while since i have used `libgdx` but:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(255/255.0f, 109/255.0f, 120/255.0f, 1f);
shapeRenderer.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, 270);
Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(lineWidth)
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Might do the trick.

Comment: Not that a `glLineWidth` other than `1.0` is not supported in all OpenGL ES implementations.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680908/libgdx-gl10-gllinewidth?rq=1

Comment: And also, the width won't be the same on android and desktop