# Line size in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, line

Is there a way to set line size in Shape Renderer to other than 1? Alternative solution could be to draw a rectangle, but that seems to be way to power consuming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked at a bunch of other questions and it seems that scaling a shape renderer line is not a good option. Please have a look at this: [Increasing the width of line drawn using Shape Renderer in LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650619/increasing-the-width-of-line-drawn-using-shape-renderer-in-libgdx)